# Как узнать о подключении флешки?

Tags: windows, usb, service

Всем привет :) Я пишу сервис, задача которого отловить момент подключения флешки и записать её название в текстовый файл. Я пробовал **RegisterDeviceNotification**, но у меня почему-то не заработало. Существуют ли какие-то другие способы решить задачу?

Answer (score 2):

Другой способ решить эту задачу - это использовать [`SHChangeNotifyRegister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762120.aspx), которая в конечном счете сама использует `RegisterDeviceNotification` и отслеживать события `SHCNE_DRIVEADD`. [Пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940348.aspx) работы.